# How to generate Kindle AZK on the command line from mobi/epub?

Tags: kindle, mobi, ios

I'm trying to generate an AZK file from the command line.

I need an AZK file because I need to test my Kindle books on iOS devices. These books are in Japanese, which currently is not supported for Enhanced Typesetting, so I need to sideload an AZK file. It's a pain to generate this in Kindle Previewer each time, so I want to automate the process.

The source file is an epub.

I convert the epub with Kindle Previewer 3 via the command line:

`kindlepreviewer myfile.epub -convert -showpreview`

This will create a mobi from the epub and then launch Kindle Previewer.  From Kindle Previewer, I can then go to File->Export and output an AZK-- this is the part I want to automate.

It seems there was a [tool called Gozak](https://libraries.io/go/github.com%2Ftooolbox%2Fgozak) for doing this but it's not available anymore.

I tried running **azkcreator** via the path in MacOS but it just segfaults:

```
➜  ~ /Applications/Kindle\ Previewer\ 3.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/azkcreator
[1]    18208 segmentation fault  /Applications/Kindle\ Previewer\ 3.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/azkcreator
```

So, my guess is that there is no way to create an AZK file from the command line at the moment-- but I hope someone can prove me wrong!

Comment: If you create a repo called `gozak` on Github, I will give you a PR with the source.

Comment: @MattMc Thanks! https://github.com/ptmkenny/gozak

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't directly convert from the command line using Kindle Previewer. You also can't convert multiple files.

But there is a [plugin for Calibre](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kindle_Previewer#Calibre_plugin) that would allow you to do it. Now you use [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) to convert from the command line using the Calibre executable [ebook-convert](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html):

```
ebook-convert myfile.input_format myfile.output_format -h
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure you can generate an AZK from the command line. From https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/KindleGen

> Note that Kindle Previewer is currently the only way to generate AZK files for iOS use.

Not the answer you seek, but an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate via caliber..

Comment: Welcome to the site Anthony! If you could link to some documentation and put a summary of the steps in your answer (in case the link ever changes) that would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/6142)